# Black screen after toggling fullscreen mode (panolens.js/three.js)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using a library called [panolens](https://github.com/pchen66/panolens.js) to show a panoramic (360 dgree) view, which depends on [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js), my app has two views, one of them has custom content and the other used as a container for panolens, by default the first view is visible (has `display: block`) and the panolens container is hidden (has `display: none`) and there is two buttons to toggle between the two views (flips the display property for each container), also there is a button to switch to full screen mode using the `requestFullscreen` method.

When I toggle full screen mode (enter then exit full screen mode) and then switch to the panoles view, it shows a black screen.

Live example

- [codepen](https://codepen.io/sahilmob/pen/YzqydyP)

Browser

- [x] All of them

OS

- [x] All of them

Comment: Do you see any errors or warnings in the browser console?

Comment: @Mugen87 no, there is no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I verified your problem on Google chrome, and changed the following property in your CSS file:

```
#container-y{
/*   display: none; */
}
```

Then it behaves as expected.

Somehow initializing the Panolens container to *display : none* confuses panolens-canvas, which is auto-generated inside the container id (here container-y), therefore it has width and height set to zero.